# Is it possible to set a subpackage as the root of the source DISPLAY in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package-explorer

So I have this Java project, and I use Eclipse Indigo.

The source packages all start with A.B (not really, but you get it) and in the Eclipse Package Explorer, I see:

- A

  - B

    - package1
    - package2

It's pointless to see A.B.  Is there a way, using the Package Explorer in hierarchical mode, to NOT see A.B and just see this:

- package1
- package2

Thanks very much in advance.  It seems there should be a way, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it isn't great but as it turns out I just sort of found a way.

Define a working set where src, src/A, and src/A/B are NOT part of the working set.  But src/A/B/package1 and src/A/B/package2 ARE part of the working set.

In hierarchical mode, the Package Explorer shows the tree as:

- A.B

  - package1
  - package2

It isn't perfect (I'd still like not to see A.B at all) but it is better than what I had -- the package prefix is actually 4 segments long.

But if anyone knows how to hide A.B completely, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Nope, never mind, that really doesn't change anything.  Ugh.  I'm slipping here.